# trying to replicate table to multiple databases on slave server

Tags: mysql

I've got a single table in a master DB that I would like to replicate to multiple databases on one slave server. Like this:

```
masterDB.tableA -> slaveDB1.tableA
masterDB.tableA -> slaveDB2.tableA
```

slaveDB1 and slaveDB2 are on the same slave server. Is this possible?

I can get slaveDB1's replication working no problem, but it's as it it's ignoring the command in my.cnf for slaveDB2:

```
replicate-rewrite-db="masterDB->slaveDB1"
replicate-rewrite-db="masterDB->slaveDB2"

replicate-wild-do-table=slaveDB1.tableA%
replicate-wild-do-table=slaveDB2.tableA%
```

Am I missing something, or can this just not be done with replication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html)

> To specify multiple rewrites, use this option multiple times. The server uses the first one with a from_name value that matches.

This suggests it won't work as it will only take into account the first of your two replicate-rewrite-db options (which is the behaviour you're seeing).

Comment: I saw that too, which is where I got stuck.  Thanks - I think you and @Aknosis are both right.  A second slave instance or bust!

Comment: @jason_mc99 I'm interested to know why you're looking at this sort of set up. Maybe there's a better solution we can suggest? Also on SO you need to make sure you accept answers and up vote. Maybe if both answers helped you equally you could accept one and up vote the other!

Comment: thanks!  I can't upvote as I apparently don't have the rep for it, but I will accept an answer!

What I'm trying to do is push a master DB of mainly-static information out to DBs that are specific to multiple companies in my organization.  Ideally I will just make a change to the "master" DB, and then have it show up in each company's individual database.  The data is essentially static, so cascade deletes and orphaned records aren't a concern.

(The reason we're trying to do this is to reduce our reliance on foreign keys in external databases to make our MVC code simpler.)

Comment: @jason_mc99 Thanks for the accept! Make sure you come back and vote up Aknosis when you have enough rep. In terms of your problem, replication is going to be tricky if you have more than a small number of different DBs on a single machine. Without knowing the dimensions of your app, hard to suggest a solution. Have you looked at: one static schema for all the apps (each with their own proprietary schema); NoSQL options; some kind of version-control/trigger solution; some kind of build/auto-deploy solution?

Comment: right now we're thinking we may just update the copies of the databases via cron jobs - it's just a hassle.  NoSQL options sound interesting - any ideas? I will definitely come back to upvote @Asknosis once I get the rep.

Comment: @jason_mc99 Not an expert on NoSQL databases but I do know most of them are built for scalability so replication between multiple instances is a common feature.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know of to accomplish this would be to run multiple mysqld instances on your slave server and then have a replicate-rewrite-db set for each one.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-servers.html